# Java Escaping Characters in RegEx

Tags: java, regex, string

I have the below RegEx to match email address

```
[-0-9a-zA-Z.+_]+@[-0-9a-zA-Z.+_]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4}
```

AM trying to escape the characters as below but am still getting java compilation error. Could someone please help me to escape characters in the above RegEx?

```
String pattern = "\\[-0-9a-zA-Z\\.\\+_\\]\\+@\\[-0-9a-zA-Z\\.\\+_\\]+\\\.\\[a-zA-Z\\]\\{2,4\\}";
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The escaped regex is:

```
"[-0-9a-zA-Z.+_]+@[-0-9a-zA-Z.+_]+\\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4}"
```

Comment: ... the point being that characters like `.` and `+` don't need to be escaped at all inside square bracket character classes as they are treated as literals by default.  The _only_ thing that needs to be escaped from Java is the backslash before the literal dot.